# How to add multiple users to Access Control List for many files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I figured out how to give access to other AWS accounts to an S3 bucket. If I understand correctly, the permissions given to the bucket is not the same as the permissions give to each object in the bucket. I want all the objects in the bucket to have the same permissions.

To give users list access to the bucket:

```
aws2 s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket BucketName --grant-read-acp emailaddress=email1@emal.com,emailaddress=email2@emal.com,… --grant-read emailaddress=email1@emal.com,emailaddress=email2@emal.com,…
```

To give users list access to one object:

```
aws2 s3api put-object-acl --bucket BucketName --key myObject.txt --grant-read-acp emailaddress=email1@emal.com,emailaddress=email2@emal.com --grant-read emailaddress=email1@emal.com,emailaddress=email2@emal.com
```

However, I have hundreds of thousands of objects on S3. How do I grant the same access to all of them using the Amazon Web Service Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)?

Comment: Side-note: If you are wanting to grant access to a bucket (or sub-folder) to a specific group of users, you could instead create an IAM Group with those users, then grant permission to that IAM Group. This way, any additional files in that bucket/folder will also be accessible to those users.

Comment: I have seen this suggestion a few times. But if I want to associate the S3 permissions with a user's account (via their email), I don't think you can link an IAM role with another user's account.

Comment: My suggestion is not related to IAM Roles. I was recommending creating an IAM Group and putting the desired IAM Users within that IAM Group. Then, add a policy to the IAM Group. This is good for whole buckets or sub-directories, but is not good for an ad-hoc selection of objects.

Comment: The use of `emailAddress` seems a bit odd. It might be associated only with the root login for an Account rather than specific users. This is because IAM Users do not have email addresses stored against their IAM User record.

Comment: If creating an IAM group requires me to create IAM roles, and I am not able to associate those roles with individual AWS accounts, then creating an IAM group is not what I want to do.

Comment: And yes, I do not want to create IAM roles. I want to give access to AWS accounts using emailAddress or some other approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208346/discussion-between-john-rotenstein-and-joseph-konan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based upon the requirements of:

- Grant Read & List access to whole bucket
- To a list of AWS Accounts

You can attach a Bucket Policy to the Amazon S3 bucket with a list of AWS Account IDs:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-1:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-2:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-3:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will give access if they use their root login (where they login via an email address), and I think it will also work for an IAM User in their account as long as they have been granted sufficient IAM permissions for Amazon S3 within their own account. (eg `s3:*` or, more safely, `s3:GetObject` and `s3:ListBucket` for the desired bucket)

Comment: I just needed to explicitly specify the Principal using the users' CanonicalUser, and this work! Tested on ~30 users, they can confirm they now have access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for **is** `put-bucket-acl`. Here is the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-acl.html).

The example provided is:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket MyBucket --grant-full-control emailaddress=user1@example.com,emailaddress=user2@example.com --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
```

In your example, you only have the flag `--grant-read-acp` this does not grant access to the objects in the bucket. Per the documentation, `--grant-read-acp` "Allows grantee to read the bucket ACL". Not very useful in your case.

Where as `--grant-full-control` gives read, write, read ACP, and write ACP to the bucket. If you look at the documentation I linked, you can see all the flags allowed.

Comment: I only want other users to have list and read permissions, not full control. I don't see an option for this in the put-bucket-acl, though I am able to achieve this behavior object-by-object using put-object-acl. This is okay for 1 file, but what about 100k files?

Comment: I understand having --grant-read-acl and --grant-read. The problem is not being able to give privileges to an individual file. It is how to grant the same privileges to many files.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are wanting. With `put-bucket-acl` you can grant a user access to all files in the bucket. However, you don't want that, you want each individual file to have been given access, why would you want that over the full bucket access?

Comment: No, `--grant-read` doesn't allow the target user actually read the object, only list the bucket contents

Answer (score 0):

Since you "want all the objects in the bucket to have the same permissions", and you wish to apply the permissions to a set of users, I would recommend:

- Create an **IAM Group**
- Assign the desired **IAM Users** to the IAM Group
- Add a policy to the IAM Group that grants access to the bucket

Here is an example from [User Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex0):

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

You can modify the policy as desired. The above policy grants permission to:

- See a list of all buckets
- List the contents of a specific bucket
- Get/Put/Delete the contents of a specific bucket

Comment: I want to give other people's AWS accounts privileges, not IAM users. If I understand correctly, I cannot create IAM roles associated with the AWS accounts of individuals, so this is not what I want to do.